# Kotlin: Could not instantiate CouroutineWorker (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I'm trying to add periodic (daily) notifications to my app with a different title pulled from a Room DB based on the current date. I'm using Dagger-Hilt and Jetpack compose.

This is the error that appears in Logcat when the time comes for the Worker to do its work:

```
Could not instantiate com.example.myapp.ui.notifications.NotificationsWorker
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.myapp.ui.notifications.NotificationsWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2201)
    at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:243)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:145)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Could not create Worker com.example.myapp.ui.notifications.NotificationsWorker
```

Here's the rest of the setup:

**NotificationsWorker**

```kotlin
class NotificationsWorker(
    context: Context,
    workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
    private val repository: MyRepository
): CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        val today = LocalDate.now()
        var dailyItem = ""
        repository.getDailyItem(today).collect {
            dailyItem = it.title
        }

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "myChannelId")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(dailyItem)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    applicationContext,
                    Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        MainActivity(),
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
                        1
                    )
                }
            }

            notify(1, builder.build())
        }

        return Result.success()
    }

}
```

**NotificationsScheduler** called from a ViewModel

```kotlin
class NotificationsScheduler @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) {

    fun scheduleNotification(hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
        val now = Calendar.getInstance()
        val target = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
        }

        val timeDiff = target.timeInMillis - now.timeInMillis

        val notificationRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationsWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag("daily_item")
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                "myapp_notification_work",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE,
                notificationRequest
            )

    }
}
```

I can confirm that requesting `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission works fine. The app targets API 33.

Could you help me figure out what's wrong with the `NotificationsWorker`, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't setup hilt-worker properly.

1. Worker classes should be annotated by [@HiltWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/hilt/work/HiltWorker).
2. Hilt-WorkerFactory should be injected manually on WorkManager creation.

   2-1. WorkManager version 2.6.0-alpha01 or higher.
   configure your own WorkManager initializer while disabling default WorkManager initializer to inject HiltWorkerFactory to the WorkerManger.
   2-2. WorkManager lower version, construct the WorkManger provider like below

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class ExampleApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

  @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

  override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
      Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

[hilt-worker](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack?hl=en#workmanager)

Comment: Thank you! I've reconfigured the Worker and the Application. Now there's no java error. But there's also no notification being shown, even though it's supposed to be scheduled. :(

Comment: In App Inspection, the NotificationsWorker task shows State: Failed.

Comment: @zkvvoob You're requesting permission from invalid Activity inside the worker that will cause exception. You must request permission from valid live activity.

Comment: I see. Well, originally the permission is requested in a `SettingsScreen`, which is a `@Composable` function, using Acompanist/Permissions. However, Android Studio insists on this check when I write `notify(13, builder.build())`: `Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException`. How do I get around this, please?